# SOR algorithm presents an unexpecte behaviour (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I must solve the system Ax = b using SOR method. omega is 1.2, tolerance is 10^-4 and the iteration starts with 0,0,0

A = [7,-1,-4;1,5,3;2,-1,4]

b = [4,4,3]'

A is diagonally dominant so I expect the solution to converge. However, the result I get is rather strange.

x =     4.633748588560370e+67

y =    -5.235501743394227e+67

z =    -5.247746350370127e+67

I used the algorithm provided [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66570-sor-method). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If A was symmetric positive definite then omega = 1.2 would be guaranteed to converge.  Try something like omega = 0.8.